# How to tell Ninject to inject the same instance for nested constructors?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a Windows Service application, where I would like to use Ninject for my service classes. There are some service classes which use other, let's say "lower level", or more generic service classes. Each service usually needs a repository for data access.

So for example I have an IRepository interface, an IServices1 and an IServices2 interface. There are Services1 and Services2 implementations of the latter two, both having a constructor parameter of type IRepository. Now assume that implementation of Services1 would like to use some methods of IServices2 interface, so I add another constructor parameter to Services1 with type IServices2. Now when I manually instantiate the Services1 class, I would do tings like:

```
var repo = new MyRepository(); // implementing IRepository
var service1 = new Services1(repo, new Services2(repo));
```

This way I can ensure that both services are going to work with the same repository (which is a basic requirement for me).

How can I use Ninject for this scneario to prepare an IServices1 instance for me with the proper IRepository injection? Or do I have any major design mistake with this approach?

I'm not on MVC platform, so I don't have the request scope here, which I think would do the task if it were MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the NamedScope extension. There are examples for this scenario.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki

Comment: Thank you for the link, the InCallScope seems to be just what I need, I will give it a try soon.